# Regex Check Char Location

Tags: regex, xml, vb.net

I need to verify a Swedish postal code which must be 6 characters long. There must be a space for the 4th character.

An example is 114 55

I know I can verify the length being 6 with `^[a-zA-Z]{6}$` but can I verify the 4th char is a space and verify the length as well?

This must be regex as it is stored in an xml file which is parsed

I am looking at the regex provided, as well as some other solutions and for the most part it works.

I now see I need to validate 11455 or 114 55, but I can not validate 11455- 9085 or 11455 6625.

I am using the regex `^\d{5}|(\d{3}\s\d{2})$`, but it is also considering the last two as valid, how can I exclude this?

Looking into this more I have one case I can not solve. IF the postal code is put in as 60922- 62264 the last 5 digits are recognized as valid.

My regex is `(\d{5}$)|(\d{3}\s\d{2}$)` and it works for all cases except for the one just mentioned.

Any advice?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]{3} [a-zA-Z]{2}$`. For digits use `\d`

Comment: `^\d{3} \d{2}$` is 4 digits, space, 3 digits if thats what your after

Comment: @AlexK. I would assume this: `^\d{3}\s\d{2}$`. The regex you supplied does 4, space and 3 not 3, space and 2... This works as well: `\d{3}\s\d{2}` https://regex101.com/r/aJ0yO8/1

Comment: Note that `\d` matches "the decimal digits of a number of other character sets" - [Character Classes in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DigitCharacter), e.g. ٣, *unless* you specify ECMAScript-compliant behavior, whereupon it is equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Comment: I have been working away at this, I have one test case that I can not figure out if anyone wants to give it a shot let me know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As much fun as I was having learning about regex, I have a deadline and I decided to google the regex to validate Sweden's postal codes and I found this

```
^(s-|S-){0,1}[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{2}$
```

Which works in every case so far!